# Not getting data from parse server

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve data from Parse Server which I posted by other app.

I want to get the last added row or current row from table but I don't know how to do it. I am trying this:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // row of Object Id "Current USer"
            } else {
                // error
            }
        }
    });
```

and I am importing these classes:

```
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
```

but still I am getting error on

```
FindCallback<ParseObject>()
```

that give implementation of `p.v.done();`, now please help me for that.

Comment: did you added the internet permission ?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Parse.com won't let you query the special classes as the regular ones. That means you cannot obtain `ParseUser` with `ParseQuery<ParseObject>` you have to use `ParseQuery<ParseUser>`.

Also querying for special `objectId` does not work, you have to replace

```
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "your_object_id")
```

with

```
query.getInBackground("your_object_id", GetCallback...)
```

The full example of what you need is

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getInBackground(ParseUser.getCurrentUser(), new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // row of Object Id "Current USer"
        } else {
            // error
        }
    }
});
```

Please read the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-querying) before asking any questions, Parse is documented very well.